# Clear dropdown selection when search input is entered

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Trying to create a proof of concept using angular right now. I have this [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uk6B4Tgq1HrPg3lHD7gM?p=preview) where if I choose an option from a dropdown it will display a list of items from an `$http.get( )`. I have a search input as well, and when I enter text I want that to be able to make it's own `$http.get( )` call and display data in the same list as the list from above. I am just having trouble getting it all to work together. I want the user to be able to either select from dropdown or search, but not both.

Here is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-rc.0" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div>
    <select ng-options="post as post.id for post in allPosts" ng-model="selectPost" ng-change="select()">
      <option value="">--select--</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="search()" />
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="item in records | orderBy:'Name':reverse">
        {{item.email}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Javascript:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var records;
    $scope.selectPost = '';
    $scope.searchText = '';
    $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').success(function(data1) {

      $scope.allPosts = data1;
      $scope.total = $scope.allPosts.length;
    });

    $scope.select = function() {
      $scope.searchText = '';
      $scope.search = $scope.selectPost;
      // really, the URL should tell it which posts to get
      // but because this is not a real server, we filter here
      $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments').success(function(data2) {
        $scope.records = [];
        data2.forEach(function(r) {
          if (r && r.postId && r.postId === $scope.selectPost.id) {
            $scope.records.push(r);
          }
        });
      });
    };

    $scope.search = function() {
      //clear the select, go here http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments
      //and display/filter emails based on the search input
    };



  });
```

As you can see when the search input is entered I want to call the `search( )` function and clear the select input and go do another ajax call and fill the `<li>` with the emails that match what is searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the line

```
$scope.search = $scope.selectPost;
```

overwrites the search function so remove that line.

Then, in the search function you can easily reset the select element, and filter the results by email instead of ID.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BU3s1aNS8b0ChT29D2J5?p=preview

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. As @nada mentioned too I was overwriting the search function :p. But thank you for helping me with this. Major kudos.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring $scope.search twice

Change the function name `$scope.search` to some other like:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="tsearch()" />
```

Angular:

```
      $scope.tsearch = function() {
          //clear the select
          $scope.selectPost = '';

          $scope.search = $scope.searchText;
          $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments').success(function(data2) {
              $scope.records = [];
              data2.forEach(function(r) {
                  if (r && r.postId && r.postId === $scope.selectPost.id) {
                      $scope.records.push(r);
                  }
              });
         });
    };
```

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't even catch that I had search higher up! Well how then do I display the `emails` that contain the same characters as what I search for?